# What's the difference between Pandemic Legacy Red and Blue?

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-1

So, basically what the title says. Is there any difference at all in the contents of the boxes or anything else? (without spoilers!)

Maybe it'll make a difference in "Season 2"? (it does say "Season 1" on the box after all).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The contents of the two boxes are identical. The Red and Blue boxes are for people who want to run two campaigns at the same time - for example, with two different gaming groups - to help distinguish between the games.

Comment: Absolutely this, and what a great way to sell games :D